# How can I gradually make an array sparser?

Tags: php, language-agnostic

I have a fully-populated array of values, and I would like to arbitrarily remove elements from this array with more removed towards the far end.

For example, given input ( where a . signifies a populated index )

```
............................................
```

I would like something like

```
....... . ...  .. .  .  ..    .          .
```

My first thought was to count the elements, then iterate over the array generating a random number somewhere between the current index and the total size of the array, eg:

```
if ( mt_rand( 0, $total ) > $total - $current_index ) 
    //remove this element
```

however, as this entails making a random number each time the loop goes round it becomes very arduous.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Could you randomize the order of the array once and then just step through it?

Comment: @BrianAdkins, i'm not sure i understand. once i'd randomized and killed off a few elements, how would I sort it and get it to tend to put empty elements in the higher positions?

Comment: @djb take a look at [`usort`](http://kr.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to flip a weighted coin for each entry with coin flips more weighted towards the end. For example, if the array is size n, for each entry you could choose a random number from `0` to `n-1` and only keep the value if the index is less than or equal to the random number. (That is, keep each entry with probability `1 - index/total`.) This has the nice advantage that if you're going to be compacting your array anyways, and you're using a good enough but efficient random number generator (could be a simple integer hash over a nonce), it's going to be rather fast for memory access.

On the other hand if you're only blanking out a few items and aren't rearranging the array, you can go with some sort of weighted random number generator that more often chooses numbers that are toward the end of the index. For example, if you have a random number generator that generates floats in the value of [0,1] (closed or open bounds not mattering that much likely), consider obtaining such a random float `r` and squaring it. This will tend to prefer lower values. You can fix this by flipping it around: `1-r^2`. Of course, you need this to be in your index range of `0` to `n - 1`, so take `floor(n * (1 - r^2))` and also round `n` down to `n-1`.

There's practically an infinite number of variations on both of these techniques.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite probably not the best/most efficient way to do this, but it is the best I can come up with and [it does work](http://codepad.org/jg1fg9Sb).

*N.B. the codepad example takes a long time to execute, but this is because of the pretty-print loop I added to the end so you can see it visibly working. If you remove the inner loop, execution time drops to acceptable levels.*

```
<?php

  $array = range(0, 99);

  for ($i = 0, $count = count($array); $i < $count; $i++) {

    // Get array keys
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    // Get a random number between 0 and count($keys) - 1
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1);

    // Cut $rand elements off the beginning of the keys
    $keys = array_slice($keys, $rand);

    // Unset a random key from the remaining keys
    unset($array[$keys[array_rand($keys)]]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method isn't random- it works by you defining a function, and its inverse. Different functions, with different constant coefficients will have different distribution characteristics.

The results are very pattern like, as expected when mapping a continuous function to a discrete structure like an array.

Here's an example using a quadratic function. You could try varying the constant.

demo: http://codepad.org/ojU3s9xM

```
#as in y = x^2 / 7;
function y($x) {
    return $x * $x / 7;
}
function x($y) {
    return 7 * sqrt($y);
}

$theArray = range(0,100);
$size = count($theArray);

//use func inverse to find the max value we can input to $y() without going out of array bounds
$maximumX = x($size);
for ($i=0; $i<$maximumX; $i++) {
    $index = (int) y($i);

    //unset the index if it still exists, else, the next greatest index
    while (!isset($theArray[$index]) && $index < $size) {
        $index++;
    }

    unset($theArray[$index]);
}




for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    printf("[%-3s]", isset($theArray[$i]) ? $theArray[$i] : '');
}
```